# Using AJAX to call Node.js file to send SMS message

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, twilio

I'm new to Node.js but I understand that it's on the server-side. When I run my app.js file in Terminal, it sends the text message, but what I'm ultimately trying to do is have the user finish the form, and upon button press, send them a text message to verify their submission. I'm using the Twilio service to help accomplish this. It's currently not sending a message on button press.

Here's my app.js file:

```
var accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
var authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

app.get('/testtwilio', function(req, res) {
  client.messages.create({
    to: "+1receivingNumber",
    from: "+myTwilioNumber",
    body: "Testing, testing, testing"
  }, function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(message.sid);
    }
  });
})
```

And my Javascript file:

```
$('#buttons').on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/testtwilio',
    data: {
      "To": userCellPhone,
      "From": "+1myTwilioNumber",
      "Body": "Ahoy! Testing"
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      ...
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

And lastly, my html button:

```
<button type="submit" id="buttons" class="buttons">SUBMIT</button>
```

Honestly, I'm not even sure this is possible, but I've been searching forever and can't really find any direct solution. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `app.get` and `type: 'POST'` Hopefully this should give you a hint on where you've gone wrong. If not, you can read [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/tr/api.html#app.post.method)

Comment: I'm thinking it should be changed to type: 'GET'?

Comment: Other way around, change `app.get` to `app.post`. You want to make a POST request from the client, the reason it's not working right now is that you're making a POST request from the client but have it set up to expect a GET.

Comment: @mur7ay GET is for retrieving data, in your case you want to send data via a SMS service so it's better to use POST. GET should be used only for getting data.

Comment: Hmm.. I made the switch to POST but it's still not sending.

Comment: Any errors in the browsers console from the ajax. What about the variable userCellPhone how do you get the value for this?

Comment: When I try to run the above app.js in the terminal now it's giving me an error saying: ReferenceError: app is not defined

Comment: When it's not within the function, it runs fine in the terminal with no error and the message is sent.

Comment: Yup, that's what it is now because I moved the code outside and commented out app.post and everything else inside and it send.

Comment: How do you initialize the app object. var app = .... ?

Comment: It's not truly defined. I watched two different tutorials from two different individuals that used app.somethingOrAnother and assumed it was just a Node.js thing.

Comment: It looks like this guy has it as var app = express();  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMFhtWm2Lno

Comment: ...at the 2:39 minute mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `app` variable is undefined.  If you want to use the `express` framework like in the tutorials you've followed, you need to register it in your app.js like follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Combined with the answers/comments about POST, that should see you on your way.

Nb. you'll need to install express in your node modules.  From the command line in your root directory:

`npm install --save express`

Answer (score 3):

nodeJs route expects GET. But your ajax makes POST request. Try:

```
app.post('/testtwilio', ...
```

Comment: I made the change to app.post like you suggested but for some reason, it still isn't sending.